# Is there a possibility to hide the code from end users?

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have written a PowerShell script to automate some tasks for end users.
I don't want to reveal the code/logic to my end user.

Is there any way to pack this in to a EXE.
Basically, i don't want to reveal the code.

Can some one suggest on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PowerShell script to exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338017/convert-powershell-script-to-exe)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple program to convert a PowerShell script into a .exe

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PS2EXE-Convert-PowerShell-9e4e07f1

There would probably be some way to reverse engineer the original PowerShell script if a technical user was really motivated to do so though.