# Convert multiple PowerShell scripts into an Exe file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell

I have few powershell script in orders. 
Can I convert the powershell scripts into one exe file ? I need set up it to run in order. Example, once installing with first script, second script need be installed and followed by 3,4,5 scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplest case, you can use the following approach to **merge your scripts into a single script** that you can then package as an executable:

```
$scripts = 'script1.ps1', 'script2.ps1', 'script3.ps1'
(Get-Item $scripts | ForEach-Object { 
  "& {{`n{0}`n}}" -f (Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName) 
}) -join "`n`n" > 'combined.ps1'
```

Note that this is a simplistic, but extensible approach: As written, there is no support for parameters, and no error handling: the respective contents of the original scripts are simply executed (`&`) in sequence, as script blocks (`{ ... }`).

You can **compile the combined script, `combined.ps1` to an executable**, say, `combined.exe`, as follows, using the [PS2EXE-GUI](https://github.com/MScholtes/TechNet-Gallery/tree/master/PS2EXE-GUI) project's `ps2exe.ps1` script (an updated and more fully featured version of the popular original, but obsolescent PS2EXE project).

```
# Create a PSv2-compatible executable.
# Omit -runtime20 to create an executable for the same PowerShell version
# that runs the script.
ps2exe -inputFile combined.ps1 -outputFile combined.exe -runtime20
```

**Caveat**: Generally, running the resulting executable requires the executing machine to have PowerShell installed, but **due to targeting `-runtime20`** - in an effort to be v2-compatible -  the **.NET Framework 2.0 CLR must also be installed** (note that it also comes with .NET Framework **3.5**), which is no longer true by default in recent versions of Windows.

Comment: it may be worth adding a version of this answer here, I think your answer if far more detailed and likely of better use - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338017/convert-powershell-script-to-exe

Comment: Thanks, @Matthew, but this answer is too specifically tailored to this question; generalizing it in order to make it useful as an answer to the linked question would require quite a bit more effort.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0, I have created a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59993465/139212